# How can I exclude specific tables or columns from DACPAC deployment in Azure DevOps pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I am using Azure DevOps pipelines to deploy a DACPAC to update my SQL Server database. However, I need to exclude certain objects like tables/sp's/indexes from being updated during the deployment .Is there a way to achieve this level of granularity in DACPAC deployments? If so, what steps or configurations should I use to achieve this?

Comment: From this document for [SqlAzureDacpacDeploymentV1](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SqlAzureDacpacDeploymentV1/README.md), this task is referencing to the tool of `SqlPackage.exe` to finish the workflow. So I prefer that you could check out this document for [SqlPackage Publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver16), and turn to the  `SqlPackage.exe` support. If your requirement could be achieved with the `SqlPackage.exe`, I suppose that it could also be achieved in pipeline deployment.

Comment: It has tag like /p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Users;Tables to exclude tables . 
I want to exclude a specific table. Is this possible ?

Comment: As I have suggested, your requirement could be more likely an `SqlPackage.exe` behavior. So I prefer that you could turn to SSDT for further confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the DevOps pipelines, but I assume that the process is similar as with SSDT. Then you can't exclude columns being updated easily, you can do:

1. Create projects:

- Main project with all objects except that table
- Project with single table with all columns. Reference Main project as "The same project"
- Project with single table without some columns. Reference Main project as "The same project"

2. Use deployment contributors. They allow you to control whole deployment process completely. This might not be available in cloud.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't really a usual scenario of deployment in CICD to deploy *part of the project* but you can use [deployment contributor](https://github.com/GoEddie/DeploymentContributorFilterer) which supports filtering objects by name equality or by mask like `*namepart*`

Filter should be passed as sqlpackage CLI argument:

```
...
/p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments="SqlPackageFilter=IgnoreSchema(BLAH)"
```

But if you need different objects each time to be excluded then you should reconsider your approach and fix the reason why there are always some objects in a *legal diff* state.